# Can't create protocol that is restricted to Classes in Xcode 9.3 / Swift 4.1

Tags: ios, protocols, xcode9, swift4.1

I am trying to store a list of subscribers that are ThemeListeners (mostly UIViews or UIViewControllers) and I need these to be stored weakly, otherwise the UIViewControllers are never released and I get memory leaks.
I took the WeakRef class from

https://marcosantadev.com/swift-arrays-holding-elements-weak-references/

When I put this into my project and try and compile it I get an error on the last line in Xcode 9.3:

```
'WeakRef' requires that 'ThemeListener' be a class type
```

Compiling this in Xcode 9.2 works.

```
class WeakRef<T> where T:AnyObject
{
    private(set) weak var value : T?

    init( value:T?)
    {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol ThemeListener : AnyObject
{
}

typealias WeakRefThemeListener = WeakRef<ThemeListener>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this.  I also have the same problem when trying to use NSHashTable.

Comment: [Here](https://forums.swift.org/t/error-myprotocol-is-not-convertible-to-anyobject/9817) is a good discussion about your issue. Might be helpful to look at.

Comment: @nayem Thanks for the link, I haven't tried it yet but it looks promising, will be back on this issue tomorrow.  If you wanted to summarise in an Answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your protocol should be like this:

```
protocol ThemeListener : class
{}
```